# Is there existing function that is the equivalent of Scala's drop or drop first x elements from a R vector

Tags: r, scala

Scala code:

```
List(1,2,3,4,5).drop(4) // Returns List(5)
List(1,2,3,4,5).drop(5) // Returns and empty list
```

my cooked up R code.

```
drop = function(data, number) {       
   data[(number+1): length(data)]        
}     

drop(c(1,2,3,4,5), 4) // Returns 5
// Next one doesn't work properly
drop(c(1,2,3,4,5) 5) // Returns [1] NA  5
```

I could add some exception handling to my function, but I'm wondering if I'm missing a function that would do this for me in the R base or another basic package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `tail` with a negative index would do what you want

```
tail(c(1,2,3,4,5), -4)
# [1] 5

tail(c(1,2,3,4,5), -5)
# numeric(0)
```

`tail(x,-n)` means "remove the first `n` elements from `x`".

Answer (score 0):

You can also apply the negative directly to the index and drop those observations. I would say `tail`/`head` are meant more to see the first/last parts of a given vector/data.frame/list etc, the negative argument will indeed drop the values you want, but the purpose is less clear IMO.

They're comparable in terms of performance

```
> v<-rnorm(1e6)
> system.time(v[-(1:10000)])
   user  system elapsed
  0.035   0.001   0.035
> system.time(tail(v,-10000))
   user  system elapsed
  0.037   0.000   0.037
> identical(tail(v,-10000), v[-(1:10000)])
[1] TRUE
```

Plus, with the indexing method you can drop a random sequence of elements, not just the X first/last.

```
> remove<-sample(length(v),10000)
> new<-v[-remove]
```